# Hackerrank: Count the number of palindromes in a given string

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I am solving a problem for Hackerrank where I have to count the number of palindromes in a given string.

I have the following code which counts the number of palindromes accurately but times out for large strings. How do I make the code more time-efficient?

```
def countPalindromes(s):
    num_palindrome = 0
    
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1):
            substring = s[i: j] 
            if len(substring) == 1:
                num_palindrome += 1
            else:
                for idx in range(len(substring)):
                    if substring[idx] != substring[-idx-1]:
                        num_palindrome -= 1
                        break
                num_palindrome += 1
    
    return num_palindrome
```

Comment: @BCdotWEB Yes those are very useful :) [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments) is the list

Comment: Why can't you give us the link to the problem?

Comment: @superbrain I found the same problem on [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindromic-substrings).

Comment: @Marc That might have different input size limits, time/memory limits, and test cases, though.

Comment: @Marc Oh and different allowed characters, too. For example if it's only letters, then RootTwo's solution could replace `j>=0 and k<len(s)` with sentinels, like with `s = '[' + s + ']' at the start. That would make it faster, but whether that's possible depends on the allowed input characters.

Answer (score 3):

For each position in the string your code checks all substrings that start at that position. For example, for s = 'a2b3bb3443bab' and `i` = 3, the code checks '3', '3b', '3bb', '3bb3', ..., '3bb3443bab'. That is O(n^2) strings to palindrome check.

Instead, for each position in the string, check for palindomes that are centered on that position. For example, for s = 'a2b3bb3443bab' and `i` = 3, check the substrings '3', 'b3b', and '2b3bb'.  Stop there, because no other string centered on i = 3 can be a palindrome.  It also needs to check for palindromes with an even length such as at i = 4, where we check 'bb', '3bb3' and stop at 'b3bb34'.  I think it's O(n*p) where p is the average length of a palindrome (which is less than n).  It seems to take about 2/3 as long as you code.

```
def pcount(s):
    count = 0
    
    for i in range(len(s)):
        # count the odd-length palindromes
        # centered at s[i]
        j=i
        k=i
        while j>=0 and k<len(s) and s[j] == s[k]:
            count += 1
            j -= 1
            k += 1

        # count the even-length palindromes
        # centered at s[i:i+1]
        j = i
        k = i + 1
        while j>=0 and k<len(s) and s[j] == s[k]:
            count += 1
            j -= 1
            k += 1

    return count
```

Comment: How did you measure to get "2/3"? I'd expect a better improvement from switching from O(n^3) to O(n^2).

Comment: I just used the %timeit magic in a Jupyter notebook.  But I only ran it on fairly short strings (upto 15-20 chars).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Code Review. @RootTwo already provided a more efficient approach. I'll add a couple of suggestions about your code:

- **Naming**: [prefer underscores for function names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names). `count_palindromes` instead of `countPalindromes`.
- **Checking if a string is palindrome**: this part:

  ```
  if len(substring) == 1:
      num_palindrome += 1
  else:
      for idx in range(len(substring)):
          if substring[idx] != substring[-idx-1]:
              num_palindrome -= 1
              break
      num_palindrome += 1
  ```

  Can be shorten to:

  ```
  if substring == substring[::-1]:
      num_palindrome += 1
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
            if len(substring) == 1:
                num_palindrome += 1
            else:
```

is unnecessary, as the code in the `else` part can handle single-character substrings as well. Ok, you make that special case faster, but you're making *all other cases slower*. And there are more of the latter. So this optimization attempt might very well make the solution as a whole *slower*.

If you *do* want to avoid the innermost checking for single-character substrings, an easy and faster way is to start `j` at `i + 2` instead of `i + 1` (and initialize with `num_palindrome = len(s)` to make up for it, i.e., "count" the single-character substrings in advance).

A short solution based on [RootTwo's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/252234/228314):

```
from os.path import commonprefix

def count_palindromes(s):
    return sum(len(commonprefix((s[i::-1], s[k:])))
               for i in range(len(s))
               for k in (i, i+1))
```

Demo:

```
>>> count_palindromes('foo')
4
>>> count_palindromes('mississippi')
20
```

The latter are:

- 11 palindromes of length 1
- 3 palindromes of length 2
- 1 palindrome of length 3
- 3 palindromes of length 4
- 1 palindrome of length 5
- 1 palindrome of length 7

(Pretty nice test case for correctness, I think.)